# Conditional routing base on authentication in asp.net mvc (core)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I have an action that within some operation is only for authenticated users, and some operation is only for unauthenticated users. For this case I check 'User.Identity.IsAuthenticated' condition as following code.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //Authenticated user operations
    }
    else
    {
        //Not authenticated user operations
    }

    // common operations

    return View();
}
```

Is there any way for split Index action to two action and **by using routing features** in Asp.Net Mvc, call Authenticated action for authenticated users, and NotAuthenticated action for not authenticated user

```
public IActionResult Authenticated()
{
    //Authenticated user operations
    //Common operations

    return View();
}

public IActionResult NotAuthenticated()
{
    //Not authenticated user operations
    //Common operations     

    return View();
}
```